# Apache using wrong version of PHP

Tags: ubuntu, php, web-server, apache-2.4

I'm trying to downgrade PHP from 5.5 to 5.3 (not by choice).

I thought I uninstalled php 5.5 by typing the following `sudo apt-get remove "php*"`

I then installed php 5.3 by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04)

How ever when I called `phpinfo()` inside a script and run it, I still get 
`PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19`

But when I call `php -v` from the command line I get `PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Sep  2 2016 10:56:16)`

When I cd to root directory and type `locate libphp5.so` there is only 1 path found and that's the path that Apache is already using.

**How do I tell Apache to use 5.3?**

Comment: Maybe too obvious, but  did you restart Apache?

Comment: only a couple dozens times :'(

Comment: I don't have access to an Ubuntu system atm but IIRC the Apache PHP module is a separate package named libapache2-mod-php, remove that. And the Q&A you link to mentions building PHP from source, is that what you did? Because you need additional `./configure` options to build an apache module.

Comment: Maybe your browser cached phpinfo page? Try clear browser cache and request page again.

Comment: @Slezhuk Not a chance!

Comment: @HBruijn  Ah thanks for that nugget of information. That may be where I'm going wrong. It's just the only place I could find instructions on getting an older version of php.

Comment: Read the comments on the instructions you linked to. You may be better off going to back to Ubuntu 12.04. It had PHP 5.3 in it and all dependencies will work, it's still supported (thru 2017), etc.

Comment: Make a PHP file with phpinfo() and check which php.ini is loaded, guaranteed it's loading some wrong file. Reboot the whole server if needed.

Answer (score 5):

You need to change the php module apache is using.

```
sudo a2dismod php(yourversion)
sudo a2enmod php5.3
```

Comment: you're a life saver, just upgraded my composer and laravel projects, the new versions didnt work with 8.01, so need to upgrade to 8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Check your local path for php with `which php` - since you installed php from scratch, it is most likely not installed where you Apache finds it. Best ensure your version is the only one installed.

*Remove all other versions:* You can use `dpkg -S $file`to find out which package a file belongs to. Most likely your Apache still uses the library from `libapache2-mod-php5`.

*Install your wanted version as mod_php*: Your build from scratch most likely did not include mod_php. Check with the included `./configure` script if it is enabled before installing.